# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String Model.Users.getName()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String Model.Users.getName()' on a null object reference
```

This is the code from above

```
TextView userNameTextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
CircleImageView profileImageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);
```

And I get at these next lines that error:

```
userNameTextView.setText(Prevalent.currentonlineUser.getName());    
Picasso.get().load(Prevalent.currentonlineUser.getImage()).placeholder(R.mipmap.profile).into(profileImageView);
```

I do not know why because I initialized them. I saw there are other posts with this error, but I do not know what to change at my code in order to be fine. Also, I have this class where I have the constructor, get and set methods;

```
package Model;

public class Users {
    private String name="",image="";

    public Users()
    {

    }

    public Users(String name,String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: `Prevalent.currentonlineUser.getName()` -> `Prevalent.currentonlineUser` is likely `null` there.

Comment: Yes, but how can I fix it?

Comment: create an [mcve] and post it here. You will likely already be finding the error by building the [mcve], but if you don't, the code you will be able to post here will enable others to answer that question.

Comment: Can provide your AndroidManifest.xml Problem might be there. I faced the same issue and fixrd it by changing Manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Glide.with(this).load().into(); method instead of Picasso.

Comment: The OP is having an issue with a null pointer exception, changing the image loading library won't fix their problem!